# working with 2 or more rest responses to call another rest service and make a list

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I'm very lost .... I'm trying to make a new rest service call combine theses 2 others responses that I have and with this response make a merge with theses 3 tables and then make a list ... but i cant. i'm new with SAPUI5 and i don't know soo much about this kind of language.

my frist rest call is execute on onInit event in my view controller.
with this result I need to use a "for"  to make other call for each Ids that i had in my first response.

my second response will make a another call for each responde that it have ...
and at the end I need to organize the lines so that the ids are all interconnected in a single table, so that I can create my list

this is my code:

```
    ], function (Device, Controller, JSONModel, Popover, Button, mobileLibrary, XMLModel) {
    "use strict";
    var propostasTotal = [];
    var propostas = [];
    var propostasDetalhada = [];
    var autores = [];
    var dadosAutores = [];
    var iCount = 0;
    var p = {};
    return Controller.extend("meusapps.testeAppOpenUI5.controller.View1", {
        onInit: function () {
            this.oModel = new JSONModel();
            this.oModel.loadData(sap.ui.require.toUrl("meusapps/testeAppOpenUI5/model") + "/model.json", null, false);
            this.getView().setModel(this.oModel);
// this is my frist call 
            var sUrl3 =
                "/api/v2/proposicoes?siglaTipo=PEC&siglaTipo=PLP&siglaTipo=PL&siglaTipo=MPV&dataInicio=2020-01-01&dataFim=2020-05-20&codSituacao=924&itens=10&ordem=desc&ordenarPor=ano";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: sUrl3,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: this.resSuccessPropostas.bind(this),
                error: this.resError

            });
        },


        resSuccessPropostas: function (data, status, req) {
            //  debugger;
            p = {};
            var myData = data.dados;
            propostas = data;

            for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                //this is my second call 
                var sUrl = '/api/v2/proposicoes/' + myData[i].id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: sUrl,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: this.resSuccessIdProposta.bind(this),
                    error: this.resError

                });

            }
           resSuccessIdProposta: function (data, status, req) {
            //debugger;
            var myData = data.dados;
            propostasDetalhada.push(myData);
            //p.detalheProposta = myData;
            // this is my third call 
            var sUrl = '/api/v2/proposicoes/' + myData.id + '/autores';
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: sUrl,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: this.resSuccessPropostaAutores.bind(this),
                error: this.resError
            });

        },



            resSuccessPropostaAutores: function (data, status, req) {

            var myData = data; autores.push(myData);
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oModel.setData(autores);


                for (var i = 0; i < propostas.dados.length; i++) {
                    p = {};
                    p.proposta = propostas.dados[i];
                    p.detalheProposta = propostasDetalhada.find(propostasDetalhada => propostasDetalhada.id === p.proposta.id);
                    propostasTotal.push(p);
                };
                for (var i = 0; i < propostasTotal.length; i++) {
                    for (var a = 0; a < autores.length; a++) {
                        for (var b = 0; b < autores[a].links.length; b++) {
                            if (autores[a].links[b].href === propostasTotal[i].detalheProposta.uriAutores) {
                                propostasTotal[i].autores = autores[a];
                                break;
                            }
                        };
                        if (propostasTotal[i].autores) {
                            break;
                        }
                    };
                };
            };
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oModel.setData(propostasTotal);

            var oList = this.getView().byId("listaProposta");
            oList.setModel(oModel, "modelProposta");
            oModel.refresh(true);

        },
```

maybe my idea is wrong ... i just want one way to do this ...

this is the result for my first call (0:N)

```
{
  "dados": [
    {
      "id": 2077498,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2077498",
      "siglaTipo": "PL",
      "codTipo": 139,
      "numero": 1600,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Altera a Lei nº 8.069, de 13 de julho de 1990, que \"dispõe sobre o Estatuto da Criança e do Adolescente, e dá outras providências\", para proibir a venda de produtos fumígenos a crianças e adolescentes."
    },
    {
      "id": 2116186,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2116186",
      "siglaTipo": "PL",
      "codTipo": 139,
      "numero": 1599,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Institui a Semana Nacional de Prevenção e Combate à Microcefalia."
    },
    {
      "id": 2236223,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236223",
      "siglaTipo": "MPV",
      "codTipo": 291,
      "numero": 918,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Cria funções de confiança destinadas à Polícia Federal e extingue cargos em comissão."
    },
    {
      "id": 2236261,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236261",
      "siglaTipo": "MPV",
      "codTipo": 291,
      "numero": 919,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Dispõe sobre o valor do salário mínimo a vigorar a partir de 1º de fevereiro de 2020."
    },
    {
      "id": 2236262,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236262",
      "siglaTipo": "MPV",
      "codTipo": 291,
      "numero": 920,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Abre crédito extraordinário, em favor do Ministério do Desenvolvimento Regional, no valor de R$ 892.000.000,00, para os fins que especifica."
    },
    {
      "id": 2236269,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236269",
      "siglaTipo": "PL",
      "codTipo": 139,
      "numero": 5,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Dispõe sobre a obrigatoriedade de aceite expresso com assinatura, de correntista, para aumento do limite de Cheque Especial em conta corrente."
    },
    {
      "id": 2236270,
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236270",
      "siglaTipo": "PL",
      "codTipo": 139,
      "numero": 6,
      "ano": 2020,
      "ementa": "Altera a Lei 9.394, de 20 de dezembro de 1996, que estabelece as diretrizes e bases da educação nacional, para tornar ilegal a progressão continuada em escolas de todo país, abolindo a organização por ciclos."
    }
```

with this result for each id I need to call the second .. (1:1)

```
{
  "dados": {
    "id": 2236270,
    "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236270",
    "siglaTipo": "PL",
    "codTipo": 139,
    "numero": 6,
    "ano": 2020,
    "ementa": "Altera a Lei 9.394, de 20 de dezembro de 1996, que estabelece as diretrizes e bases da educação nacional, para tornar ilegal a progressão continuada em escolas de todo país, abolindo a organização por ciclos.",
    "dataApresentacao": "2020-02-03T15:24",
    "uriOrgaoNumerador": null,
    "statusProposicao": {
      "dataHora": "2020-02-07T00:00",
      "sequencia": 15,
      "siglaOrgao": "CCP",
      "uriOrgao": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/orgaos/186",
      "uriUltimoRelator": null,
      "regime": "Ordinária (Art. 151, III, RICD)",
      "descricaoTramitacao": "Publicação de Proposição",
      "codTipoTramitacao": "604",
      "descricaoSituacao": "Aguardando Designação de Relator",
      "codSituacao": 907,
      "despacho": "Encaminhada à publicação. Publicação Inicial em avulso e no DCD de 08/02/20 PÁG 116",
      "url": null,
      "ambito": "Regimental"
    },
    "uriAutores": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236270/autores",
    "descricaoTipo": "Projeto de Lei",
    "ementaDetalhada": "",
    "keywords": "Alteração, Lei de Diretrizes e Bases da Educação Nacional (1996), critério, Progressão continuada de ensino, proibição, ensino fundamental, desmembramento, ciclo escolar.",
    "uriPropPrincipal": null,
    "uriPropAnterior": null,
    "uriPropPosterior": null,
    "urlInteiroTeor": "http://www.camara.gov.br/proposicoesWeb/prop_mostrarintegra?codteor=1853650",
    "urnFinal": null,
    "texto": null,
    "justificativa": null
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/2236270"
    }
  ]
}
```

and with this id i need to call this another one (1:N)

```
{
  "dados": [
    {
      "uri": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/132022",
      "nome": "MARCIO SANTILLI",
      "codTipo": 10000,
      "tipo": "Deputado",
      "ordemAssinatura": 1,
      "proponente": 1
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/proposicoes/223628/autores"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you i'm sorry for my english

Comment: Typically this kind of problem is difficult to handle when you have to make multiple levels of calls to construct the model. I would suggest that you talk to your team members and simplify the model which also means that the views need to change. the designers of the view needs to be aware of the limitations imposed by the APIs. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! i will see what i can do